# create a json object with responses from different async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

My goal is to create a JSON object, from a paragraph of text, that I can then insert as a document into MongoDB. I'm using nodejs and wanted to go for the async approach.

My JSON has parameters like so

```
{
   height:height,
   weight:weight
}
```

My logic is this

create a module with async functions that parse the text and extract weight and height using regex.

but then how would I combine all the responses from these functions into one JSON that I can import at once?

I'm thinking something like this

```
var get_height = require().height;
var get_weight = require().weight;

exports.contr = function(){
   var height,
       weight;
   get_height(text, function(err, res){
      if(err)
          throw(err)
      height=res;
   });

   get_weight(text, function(err, res){
      if(err)
          throw(err)
      weight=res;
   });
   //All other async functions
   combine_json(height, weight, ... , function(err, res){
       if(err)
          throw(err);

       console.log(res); //the json was successfully inserted into mongoDB
   }); 
}
```

I find async confusing and in the above example I'm not sure about two things

1. wouldn't `combine_json` run without waiting for the data from the previous two functions (weight, height)
2. what is the best practice to handle such cases? Should i just use sync functions and wait top-to-bottom for each one to do its thing and then run the final one or I can leverage async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to wait for the results of *two* independent asynchronous functions is to use promises and `Promise.all`. For this we'll assume `get_height` and `get_weight` return a `Promise` and can be used as such:

```
get_height().then(function (height) { console.log(height); });
```

Then it's trivial to combine two of those promises:

```
Promise.all([get_height(), get_weight()]).then(function (results) {
    combine_json(results[0], results[1]);
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for documentation and details.

Comment: just a 'callback' that these promises are totally what i needed but they are hard to wrap my head around them. Thanks for the response, man.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know nothing of Promises, you first should know how callbacks works. If you do not want a elegant solution with `Promise.all()` and you just want your code working, you need nested functions. When you are inside `get_height` callback you should to call `get_weight` and same when you are inside `get_weight` callback you should call `combine_json()` . The only problem is that you have to wait for `get_height` to call `get_weight`. This is solved with Promise.all() as it's said.

```
   get_height(text, function(err, height){
      if(err)
          throw(err);
      get_weight(text, function(err, weight){
         if(err)
            throw(err);
         //All other async functions
         combine_json(height, weight, ... , function(err, res){
             if(err)
                throw(err);
             console.log(res); //the json was successfully inserted into mongoDB
         }); 
      });
   });
```

Comment: I said in my answer that thisis the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are your best bet, but if you don't want to use them for some reason and prefer the callback style, then

```
function get_height_and_weight(text, callback) {
  var have_height = false;
  var have_weight = false;
  var result = {};

  get_height(text, function(err, height) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    have_height = true;
    result.height = height;
    if (have_weight) callback(null, result);
  });

  get_weight(text, function(err, weight) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    have_weight = true;
    result.weight = weight;
    if (have_height) callback(null, result);
  });
}
```

This is a special case of the parallel async call case which could be handled better by `async.parallel`.